# MySQL: whitespace character in field is not actually whitespace. What is it?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, whitespace

I have a string in a field in a MySQL table.

It is VARCHAR, the table encoding is utf8.

The content of the field is `one two three`

If I run `select * from table where content like '%one two%';` the row is returned.
However, if I run `update table set content = REPLACE(content, " ", "+;;");` then the result is `one two+;;three`.

So, what is that first "whitespace" character?

I'm using this table with a Ruby on Rails app.  Ruby doesn't recognize it as a whitespace character either. (e.g. if I split the string on " ", it doesn't split on the first space)

Any idea what's going on?

Thanks.

Comment: Pull that string out of the database in the Rails console and have a look at `your_string.bytes`.

Comment: Converting the "bad" space to bytes.to_a is [194, 160].  The "good" space is [32]

Comment: That's the 0xC2 0xA0 that Arjan is talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably a non breaking space character (2 bytes in UTF8: 0xC2 0xA0). That is not a space, and comparing it with a space will yield false.

You can update your table like so:

```
UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE(column, ' ', ' ');
```

Note that you should make sure that the first 'space' is actually the character you want to replace.

Comment: Do you know a quick/easy way to update my fields in MySQL to replace the non breaking space with a regular space?

Comment: only problem is it does not work.. it will replace 1 with 0 but not broken space with space